# How to search for logos to use on google images without all the stock photo sites coming up in results?

Tags: logo, stock-images, google

I'm searching for logos to derive my logo from. I get my ideas from google images, but the stock photo sites are really anonying. Is there a way to search google images without all those stock image sites coming up in my results? Or is there a better place where I can get free logo ideas where I can derive my logo from? I just need some graphics to start off from and I just do my own edits on it.

Comment: What queries / keywords are you using to search? That might make a huge difference

Answer (score 3):

Put the characters "-stock" in the search terms, without the quotes obviously.

Be very careful about "deriving" logos from others. Taking inspiration from looking at the design of other logos for some general ideas might be fine, but copying or editing other logos will probably land you in serious legal trouble. Most company logos are copyright.  I strongly advise against doing that.